# Batch code don't give correct date in new folder name

Tags: date, batch-file, cmd

I have a script that backup files from a folder to a new folder named with the current date and time, but the date does not display correct in the folder name.

Here is the code:

```
set hh=%time:~-11,2%
set /a hh=%hh%+100
set hh=%hh:~1%
Set dateseed=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%hh%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

if not exist "C:\Temp\backup\%dateseed%" mkdir "C:\Temp\backup\%dateseed%"
cd "C:\Temp\backup\%dateseed%"
copy "C:\Temp\test2" .
```

The new folder is supposed to get a name like: **20140219_100105** but gets the name "**-0-1_100115**"

What is wrong?

Comment: It works fine for me. What do you get for `echo %date%`?

Comment: echo %date% gives the correct format (2014-02-19)

Comment: If I change "dateseed=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%" to: "dateseed=%date%" i get file name "2014-01-19_100115".

This works for me now, but it would be nice to know the reson for the weird date with the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of `%date%` can be changed by the user and changes by default on different region settings so you can't rely on it for a range of machines.

Another issue is the calculation using `hh` which will be treated as Octal numbers when the first digit is zero, and in such a case the calculation will fail with an error message when the number is not valid Octal such as `09`

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause
```